# Multi items ListView will only appear on screen after on/off button is pressed. Why?

Tags: javascript

I have created a apps to list down my data in multi items Listview.

My database is Firebase. All connections are successful as I am able to see my items listed according to the format.

But in order to do so, I need to physically press the on/off button of the phone to it to sleep mode. Then press again to return back to the screen, and then the data will be listed.
I have no idea why?
Below is my code:

```
public class ListReportedHazardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference db;
    FirebaseHelper helper;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    ListView lv;
    EditText titleEditTxt, locationEditTxt, descriptionEditTxt, rankEditTxt, nameEditTxt, contactEditTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_reported_hazard);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        //INITIALIZE FIREBASE DB
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        helper = new FirebaseHelper(db);

        //ADAPTER
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, helper.retrieve());

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: But in emulator, I need to press back button then go in again, my data will be listed. And will be there throughout.

Comment: But when I install in the device, I will need to press the on/off button. Weird ??